# How can I check for a condition across rows in a matrix in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

Input:  I have a range in an excel sheet. Let's say B1:F100 = 100X5 matrix on "Sheet 1".

Now I want to count the number of rows that have "Data" in any of the columns B to F (from rows 1 to 100). i.e. I'm looking for a function, let's say, ExistIfRow(B1:F100) that will return a 100X1 array of 0s or 1s. So I can simply do a sum(ExistIfRow(B1:F100)) to get the number of rows.
I would like to be able to select 100 cells and enter this function as an array formula to get that 100X1 result in the sheet.

I hope that makes sense.

---

In addition, I attempted to create this function but it doesn't show up in my excel sheet when I try to put it in a cell. Can someone please help me see what I am doing wrong?
This function exists under "Modules" in the worksheet.

```
Function RowWiseOR(Rin As Range, Condition As Variant) As Range

Dim rw As Range
Dim Out As Variant
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

For Each rw In Rin.Rows
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rw, Condition) > 0 Then Out(i).Value = 1 Else Out(i).Value = 0
    i = i + 1
End

RowWiseOR = Out
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why "it doesn't show up", but there were a few issues with the function itself.  Specifically,

- The function should return a `Variant` array, not a `Range`
- The variable `Out` needed to be initialized as an array to hold the results
- Elements of arrays don't have a `.Value` property.  For example, use `Out(i) = 1` instead of `Out(i).Value = 1`
- `Transpose` the array before writing it out to the sheet if you want it to be a column vector.

See below for the revised function:

```vb
Function RowWiseOR(Rin As Range, Condition As Variant) As Variant

    Dim rw As Range
    Dim Out As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0

    ReDim Out(Rin.Rows.Count - 1)

    For Each rw In Rin.Rows
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rw, Condition) > 0 Then Out(i) = 1 Else Out(i) = 0
        i = i + 1
    Next

    RowWiseOR = Application.Transpose(Out)

End Function
```

Remember to enter it as an array formula.  See [here](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-feeac856-88a1-4219-95a5-40107a1b4365?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__learn_about_array) for more information.

Comment: Great. Thanks Steve. This works.
However when I try to do Countif() on this range it gives a #Value error. For eg. when I do sum(RowWiseOR(A1:C20,"data")) it gives me the right number of rows that have "data" anywhere. Using it as an array formula I can see the 20X1 array (I didn't transpose) with 0s and 1s. However when I do a countif(RowWiseOR(A1:C20,"data"),1) I would expect 5 but I get an error instead.
Can you help?

Comment: I need a little clarification.  Do you want to see the 20X1 array with '1's and '0's and then also see a single cell that contains the count of '1's in the resulting 20X1 array or do you want just the count of rows that contain 'data'?

Comment: So I want to see the 20X1 array with '1's and '0's. I can then sum this array in a single cell to get the "count of '1's in the resulting 20X1 array". 
But I'm trying to use this 20X1 array with another 20X1 array in a 'countifs()'. Does that make sense? So what I'm trying to do is countifs(<the above 20X1 array>,1,H1:H20,1). And this is what gives an error.

Comment: `CountIf` only receives 2 arguments. `CountIfs` can receive more, but all arguments after Arg1 are criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text. It sounds like you want to do an array of Logical ANDs between the two 20X1 arrays and then CountIf those. It also seems like the scope of the question has changed.  I'm happy to help you resolve this--perhaps you can edit the original question to show the two stages of the problem you are trying to solve and we can get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Countif is giving an error because countif does not work with array.
Try the same in excel and you will again get an error.

Also i do not understand why you need to create a function to count 0's or 1's. this can be easly achieved by countif formula in excel - COUNTIF(A1:C3,"data")